# After DB restart Application pool required to be recycled to restore DB connection (IIS 7)

Tags: .net, iis-7

I have got one situation, if I restart the Database connected to my web application (in .Net), I have to recycle the application pool to restore the DB connection for my application.

Without recycling of application pool, i couldn't able to connect to my application. Does anyone let me know is there a way to not to do the manual recycle the application pool to restore DB connection?

Or, there are any way to restore DB connection without recycling Application pool?

Comment: You aren't using one connection object for the whole app, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, we are using one connection object for whole application.

Comment: Stop doing that then. It's hurting for a reason. The right way to structure the application is, in the methods that actually deal with the database you should create a connection object, open it, talk to the database, close the connection and throw it away.

Comment: This is existing architecture of the application, and if will do so it will have huge impact on application. Could you please explain me what was happened when I restart the DB and why there is need to recycle the application pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The app pool is the webservices deployed on your iis instance. They
>   can either be backend services behind your website or front end
>   webservices. Either way if you are restarting SQL server instance it
>   means that these webservices are either losing their connection to the
>   database or it's become non-responsive for that DB session.

By refreshing the pool you are fundamentally restarting the application and re-establishing the DB connection(s).

Taken from

https://serverfault.com/questions/222385/what-does-recycling-the-app-pool-actually-do-exactly